# Unix Bash Remove Duplicate Lines From Directory Files?

Tags: bash, sorting, unix, directory, duplicates

I have a directory with a few hundred txt files. I need to remove all duplicate lines from each of the existing files. Every line in the entire directory should be unique regardless of the file it's in, so I need to compare and check each file against the other. Is this possible to do without altering the existing file structure? The file names need to stay the same.

Let's say all the files are in directory "foo" and the total size of the directory is 30mb.

I think I can do this through comm or awk, but I haven't found a working command line to do this and I'm unfamiliar with the syntax.

**UPDATE**
I have tried this line which I believe posts all the duplicates in the shell, but it's not removing the duplicates from the files.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0]="";next}; !($0 in a)' tmp/*
```

Comment: Please update your Q with total size of all of those files.(KBytes, MBytes, GBytes?) . Good luck.

Comment: Updated - 30mb for whole directory

Comment: Suppose `file1` and `file2` both contain a line `abracadabra`; which of the two files should be edited to remove the line?  Do you need to edit each file in situ, keeping a record of whether each line has been seen before in any of the files processed so far, and only printing the line to output if it has not been seen before?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34025284/1030675

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34022822/1030675

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{
   if(FNR==1){
       if(fs!=lfn && NR!=1){
         b[lfn]
       };
   lfn=FILENAME
   };
   if(!($0 in a)) {
        a[$0];print $0>FILENAME;
        fs=FILENAME
  }
  }
END{
    if(fs!=lfn){
         b[FILENAME]
    };
    for (i in b){
         close(i);
         printf (data) >i;
    }
}' tmp/*
```

1st Condition:

```
if(!($0 in a)) {
  a[$0];print $0>FILENAME;
  fs=FILENAME
}
```

If the current line $0 is in array `a` if not add the line to array a and to the current file being read else ignore the line. FILENAME awk built-in variable gives the name of the file being read. 
If there is at least one different line in current file being read is found flag `fs` with `FILENAME` is set.

2st Condition:

```
  if(FNR==1){
    if(fs!=lfn && NR!=1){
      b[lfn]
    };
     lfn=FILENAME
  }
```

So when next file is read `FNR==1` `fs`(last file with different line) and `lfn`(lastfilename) is compared if this differs then array `b` with index `lfn` is created.( To touch as empty file)

1st Condition:

```
  END{
      if(fs!=lfn){
           b[FILENAME]
      };
      for (i in b){
           close(i);
           printf (data) >i;
      }
  }
```

In the `END`, above condition 2 checked again to find if last file has different line. Also loops through the array `b` to touch empty file where no different lines are found.
Here I have assumed there is no order in which file are read.

This is script is not optimal but will do the work.

Comment: Thanks, I believe it's printing all the duplicates in the shell, but it's not removing duplicates found in the text files. Do you know how to have it remove duplicates from the existing files, or recreate the existing files without duplicates?

Comment: @nickyb, I just tested the (non) answer provided by Jijin P and the output is not the duplicates but a list of whats unique between all files.  In any case it does not properly answer your question.

Comment: @user3439894 Any idea how I can remove the duplicates from the existing files or recreate the existing files without duplicates? I need keep the individual files without having any duplicate lines.

Comment: @nickyb, No, sorry, I do not have a working solution for you.  It's an interesting problem and I hope someone posts a working solution for you.

Comment: Modified the answer. I hope this gives the desired output.

Comment: @JijinP, Here's an example in which the new command fails: dir has 3 text files named "1", "2" and "3" respectively. File "1" contains "one", "two", "three" (each on a separate line), file "2" contains "three"," four", "five" and file "3" contains "two", "three", "four".  File "1" and "2" get touched and file "3" is not touched at all when in reality file "3" should now contain nothing but it still contains "two", "three", "four" which are in the touched files "1" and "2". Not sure this is a fair example however his gives pause to what Jonathan Leffler asked in his comment to the OP.

Comment: @user3439894 Modified the script to empty a file that has all duplicate lines. Also I assumed there is no order in which files are read.

Comment: `printf (data) >i"` unterminated string