# Bash Directory Sorting Issue - Removing Duplicate Lines?

Tags: bash, sorting, unix, directory, duplicates

I'm using this command to merge multiple identical directories and to remove duplicate lines from each of the corresponding files:

```
for f in app1/*; do 
   bn="$(basename "$f")"
   sort -u "$f" "app2/$bn" > "app/$bn"
done
```

Is there a way to edit this so that it checks the lines of all the files and removes all the duplicates as well? I do need to keep the existing file structure with individual files.

The end result creates a directory with 300 text files that's no larger than 30mb.

**Example:**

```
**Directory app1**
*1.txt*       
a
b
c

*2.txt*
d
e
f

**Directory app2**
*1.txt*
a
b
c
g

*2.txt*
a
b
c
d
e
f

**Results in Directory app**
*1.txt*
a
b
c
g

*2.txt*
a
b
c
d
e
f

Desired Result in Directory app Should Be:
*1.txt*
a
b
c
g

*2.txt*
d
e
f
```

As you can see it's not removing the duplicate "A B C" lines from 2.txt when it's also found in 1.txt. All lines in each file should remain unique and all duplicates should be removed.

Comment: @MarcB - that's what `sort -u` does, no?

Comment: ah yeah. ... never used sort to do the uniquing. force of habit - always used uniq

Comment: nickyb, I'm not sure how your existing script fails to achieve your goal.  `sort -u file1 file2 file3` should merge the three files, sort them and uniq the result. Can you clarify why that is not what you want?  What does "checks the lines of all the files" mean?  Are you saying you want to uniq lines from files that are outside the current instance of the loop? Or something else?

Comment: I'm still new to this but the script above merges identical directories, and I believe it only removes the duplicates from identical files. It would remove identical files from a.txt and a.txt, but not a.txt and b.txt. I may need a whole separate command to remove duplicates from the entire directory, but I need to do this in a way that preserves the existing file names.

Comment: Remove identical files?  Or identical lines?  Are you looking to compare identical files, or file content? As far as I'm aware, `sort -u file1 file2 file3` is functionally equivalent to `cat file1 file2 file3 | sort | uniq`. Can you perhaps update your question to show sample input data along with your desired results?

Comment: Or ... so ... if `app1/a.txt` and `app2/a.txt` and `app3/a.txt` all exist, your script will unique their lines in an output file of `app/a.txt`. Are you saying you want to remove lines that *also* appear in `b.txt`?  If so, how do you decide whether a particular line goes in one file vs the other?

Comment: Are you trying to find dupes in different files ? Your current script will just print every line in all the files but once.

Comment: The current script merges duplicate directories with identical files and removes duplicate lines from the corresponding files.

Comment: In the expected output, would it be still correct to remove `a b c` from 1.txt and leave it in 2.txt? If not, why?

Comment: `a b c` should be unique lines that never occur more than once in any file in the directory. But at the moment it will only remove `a b c` if it's in 1.txt of direcoty A & directory B. Is there a separate command I can use that will just check the entire directory for duplicate lines and remove them?

Comment: Your "should be" results for 2.txt make no sense. Explain further **in your question**, not in comments.

Comment: @glennjackman I just updated my question and example.

Comment: @ghoti `A B C` should be removed from 2.txt

Comment: The first occurrence is in 1.txt so logically it should remove any duplicate found any where else.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34025284/1030675

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34020528/1030675

Answer (score 0):

This should probably be done with `perl -i`:

```
perl -i -n -e 'print unless $h{$_};++$h{$_}' app1/*
```

This seems to create `.bak` files in app1 (despite man page saying it won't) which you may want to eliminate after verifying the result with `rm app1/*.bak`.

Answer (score 0):

> As you can see it's not removing the duplicate "A B C" lines from
>   2.txt when it's also found in 1.txt. All lines in each file should remain unique and all duplicates should be removed.

You can accomplish this goal by applying 7171u's answer to your other question "[Unix Bash Remove Duplicate Lines From Directory Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34021753/2413201)" to the result of your command above (after having changed the `tmp/*` in his script to `app/*`, which should be trivial).